# Onclick switch back to first option

Tags: javascript, onclick, html-select, selection

If you select the option with `id="second"` you will be switched back to the option with `id="first"`.

Anyone know how to do this with onclick?

```
<select id="switchback">
  <option id="first" value="one">Switch back to first option?</option>
  <option id="second" value="two" onclick="...">Yes</option>
</select>
```

**Note: cannot use jQuery.**

Comment: You **do** want the select to automatically revert to first option ?

Comment: Yes. When you select "Yes" the first option will automatically be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **do** want the select to automatically revert to first option, you can do this :

```
document.getElementById('switchback').onchange = function(){
    if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].id=="second") {
        this.selectedIndex = 0; 
    }
};​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/qY9v8/)

But what is the point in proposing a `select`, then ? Note that you maybe you'd prefer to disable it :

```
<select id="switchback" disabled>
  <option id="first" value="one">You can't change me, lalalala...</option>
  <option id="second" value="two">And you can't see me</option>
</select>​
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/KrtTF/)

This second solution is clearer for most users.

Comment: It acts like a refresh. If you select the second option an other code gets refreshed. Ones that is done, the switch back to the first option allows the user to make a new refresh :)

Comment: I was just thinking about an alertbox or popup to alert the user, I see you already added it to your first demonstration, thanks dystroy!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/axksN/

**HTML**

```
<select id="switchback" onchange="revertBack(this)">
  <option id="first" value="one">Switch back to first option?</option>
  <option id="second" value="two">Yes</option>
  <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript**

```
function revertBack(obj){
    if(obj.value=="two"){
       obj.selectedIndex = 0;
    }
}​
```

​